# Is there a quantum circuit to find the maximum of two inputs?

Tags: programming, circuit-construction, optimization

Is there a quantum circuit (preferably on Quirk as an example) that will enable me to find the maximum from two inputs?

**Example**

- input A: 11011
- input B: 11100

**Expected output:** 11100

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please add more details? How to decide which input is the right one? Is there any function you can use for determination of the expected output?

Comment: Maybe this article would be helpful: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9607014

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with a temporary comparison to decide which input to copy over:

[image: circuit]

If you want it to run without the extra output register, you can instead CSWAP the inputs based on the comparison bit, sorting them. You can't uncompute the comparison bit until you unsort them though.